# Capitalize only first word and leave rest as it is python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a word "`biPAP`" and some other words like this I just want the output like "`BiPAP`" using python.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I TRIED tittle() but it capitalise only first word and give output Bipap

Comment: I'm sure there are functions in python that turns a character into uppercase

Comment: Do this - ```s = s[:1].upper() + s[1:]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word = 'testWord'    
word = word[0].upper() + word[1:]
```